# Prompt user for input upon bot start up

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a chatbot in dialogflow, and I want it to prompt the user for input as soon as it load. E.g

"Hi, how may I help?"

I am able to get it to response once a user says hi, but not without that input. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Dialogflow Events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-overview)

> Events allow you to invoke intents based on something that has happened instead of what a user communicates.

More specifically **Welcome** Event, you can start typing "Welcome" in the Events section of an intent

[image]

> Common events like **WELCOME** events may be auto-completed to help you pick the right event.

Comment: thanks, I know about events. Is possible to create custom events?

Comment: @C.Calzana Yes, You can also create your own custom events that can be triggered via fulfillment or the detect intent API method.