# Is it possible to bot to prompt user for input, with user input?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible once bot has been open to ask the user for input? E,g User opens bot, bot will say: "Hi, how may I help?" This will happen without users needing to type "hi" to start conversation.

Comment: Yes, you can use [events](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-overview) to put a greeting to user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prompt user for input upon bot start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467167/prompt-user-for-input-upon-bot-start-up)